# Computationally simple pseudo-Gaussian distribution with varying mean and standard deviation?

Tags: random, probability, gaussian, probability-theory

This picture from Wikipedia has a nice example of the sort of functions I'd ideally like to generate:

[image: pseudo-Gaussian distributions]

Right now I'm using the Irwin-Hall Distribution, which is more or less a polynomial approximation of the Gaussian distribution...basically, you use uniform random number generator and iterate it x times, and take the average.  The more iterations, the more like a Gaussian Distribution it is.

It's pretty nice; however I'd like to be able to have one where I can vary the mean.  For example, let's say I wanted a number between the range 0 and 10, but *around* 7.  Like, the mean (if I repeated this function multiple times) would turn out to be 7, but the actual range is 0-10.

Is there one I should look up, or should I work on doing some fancy maths with standard Gaussian distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a contradiction in your question. From one side you want normal distribution which is *symmetrical* by it's nature, from other side you want the range asymmetrically disposed to mean value.

I suspect you should try to look at other distributions density functions of which are like bell curve but asymmetrical. Like [log distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) or [beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).

Comment: I never said I wanted a normal curve; just a probability function that is shaped like the one with mean=-2 in the linked picture.  I'll look into those, thanks =)

Comment: That shape is still normal, and thus symmetric. The figure is misleading because it suggests that the range is constrained to the visible part of the x-axis shown, which is not the case, it extends to infinity in both directions. The probability of drawing from the distant tails gets fantastically small but remains non-zero. In practice you could probably clip, but your distribution would still not be what you want. I suspect the simplest approach would be to average draws from a triangular distribution with the desired mode, but I'd need to work through that to be sure.

Comment: No, come to think of it, that will just tend to normal as well -- hello Central Limit Theorem!

Answer (score 0):

Look into [generating normal random variates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-Muller_transform).  You can generate pairs of normal random variates X = N(0,1) and tranform it into ANY normal random variate Y = N(m,s) (Y = m + s*X).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the [Truncated Normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) distribution is just what the doctor ordered. It is not "computationally simple" per se, but easy to implement if you have an existing implementation of a normal distribution.

You can just generate the distribution with the mean you want, standard deviation you want, and the two ends wherever you want. You'll have to do some work beforehand to compute the mean and standard deviation of the underlying (non-truncated) normal distribution to get the mean for the TN that you want, but you can use the formulae in that article. Also note that you can adjust the variance as well using this method :)

I have Java code (based on the Commons Math framework) for both an [accurate (slower)](https://github.com/mizzao/libmao/blob/master/src/main/java/net/andrewmao/probability/TruncatedNormal.java) and [quick (less accurate)](https://github.com/mizzao/libmao/blob/master/src/main/java/net/andrewmao/probability/TruncatedNormalQuick.java) implementation of this distribution, with PDF, CDF, and sampling.