# python 3.1 - Creating normal distribution

Tags: python

I have scipy and numpy, Python v3.1

I need to create a 1D array of length 3million, using random numbers between (and including) 100-60,000. It has to fit a normal distribution.

Using  'a = numpy.random.standard_normal(3000000)', I get a normal distribution for that required length; not sure how to achieve the required range.

Comment: If you need integers — check the edge case: you may have 50% hits cut off because of rounding! Just generate 10000 numbers and count the occurences of each: they should be more-or-less equal. Here's an example of overcoming the edge case with `uniform` distribution in 0..100: `round(random.uniform(-0.5, 100+0.5))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A standard normal distribution has mean 0 and standard deviation 1. What I understand from your requirements is that you need a ((60000-100)/2, (60000-100)/2) one. Take each value from `standard_normal()` result, [multiply it by the new variance, and add the new mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standardizing_normal_random_variables).

I haven't used NumPy, but a quick search of the docs says that you can achieve what you want directly bu using [`numpy.random.normal()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html#numpy.random.normal)

One last tidbit: normal distributions are not bounded. That means there isn't a value with probability zero. Your requirements should be in terms of means and variances (or standard deviations), and not of limits.

Comment: Oops, didn't realise this existed, +1, use this method rather than mine.

Comment: Thanks for that! Took awhile to get my head around but I got there. As much a programming problem as understanding some basic statistics. Cheers.

Comment: Often however, we find values in form of ranges and just want to put a normal distribution in there. Doesn't have to be a requirement of anything. How would you then figure out the _new variance_ and _new mean_? The mean should probably be the value around which we want most values, but what about the variance?

Comment: @Zelphir The mean and variance of a sample are [well defined](http://www.randomservices.org/random/sample/Variance.html). The distribution of the sample (or of the population) may not be Normal, though. For example, the sample `[2]*100` (a list with a hundred `2`) has mean `2`, variance `0`, and an Homogeneous distribution. IOW, the distribution is a characteristic of the sample, and not something one can "put"  there.

Comment: @Apalala My wording was of course only colloquial. I think the problem is, that neither numpy nor plain Python offer such a cut off normal distribution, because mathematically speaking it would not be a normal distribution anymore. I guess if it is really important that no value is bigger or smaller than max and min, one has to write the function oneself.

Comment: @Zephir it is OK to use a pseudo-Normal distribution that respects the range. [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14517796/545637) talks about the [Truncated Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution). Scipy [implements it](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html).

Comment: This is an implementation that doesn't require Scipy: https://github.com/classner/py-rtnorm

Answer (score 6):

If you want a truly random normal distribution, you can't guarentee how far the numbers will spread.  You can reduce the probability of outliers, however, by specifying the standard deviation

```
>>> n = 3000000
>>> sigma5 = 1.0 / 1744278
>>> n * sigma5
1.7199093263803131  # Expect one values in 3 mil outside range at 5 stdev.
>>> sigma6 = 1.0 / 1 / 506800000
>>> sigma6 = 1.0 / 506800000
>>> n * sigma6
0.0059194948697711127 # Expect 0.005 values in 3 mil outside range at 6 stdev.
>>> sigma7 = 1.0 / 390600000000
>>> n * sigma7
7.6804915514592934e-06
```

Therefore, in this case, ensuring that the standard deviation is only 1/6 or 1/7 of half the range will give you reasonable confidence that your data will not exceed the range.

```
>>> range = 60000 - 100
>>> spread = (range / 2) / 6 # Anything outside of the range will be six std. dev. from the mean
>>> mean = (60000 + 100) / 2
>>> a = numpy.random.normal(loc = mean, scale = spread, size = n) 
>>> min(a)
6320.0238199673404
>>> max(a)
55044.015566089176
```

Of course, you can still can values that fall outside the range here

Comment: I used above, but the comments really helped with the understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

try this nice little method:

You'll want a method that just makes one random number.

```
import random
list = [random.randint(min,max) for i in range(numitems)]
```

This will give you a list with numitems random numbers between min and max.

Of course, 3000000 is a lot of items to have in memory. Consider making the random numbers as they are needed by the program.

Comment: `random.randrange` does not create a normal distribution. Also, the OP is asking for a NumPy array, not a list.